# Use readAsBinaryString() without an event listener

Tags: javascript, fileapi

Hello I'm making my first project with the File API on javascript, is a simple program that takes a file as an input and show the inner code of it on a Div.
I want to know if there is a way to get this code working without an event listener and event handler.
I think this is the main problem but I can't figure out how it works:

```
document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

All mi code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html>
<script>
function convert(){
var files = document.getElementById('input').files;
file = files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
var blob = file.slice(0,20);
    document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="input" name="file" />

<button onclick=convert()>Run script</button>

<div id="byte_range"></div>

</body>
```

I've seen several examples like [this one](http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/file-api/) but all of them use a code similar to this:

```
 event.target.result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. FileReader reads files *asynchronously*. That means the read happens in the background and finishes at some unspecified point in the future; it does *not immediately* return a result. The only way to retrieve the result is to listen to the event when it finishes and execute the code you want to execute *then*. This is not a problem at all, it just requires you to put the code in a callback/event handler function instead of procedurally after the `readAsBinaryString` call.

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

you do:

```
reader.onload = function (event) {
    document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = event.target.result;
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! 
I it worked, as I see there is still left a lot I have to learn about javascript and then rule the world :)